# Filebeat for gz files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

Does filebeat support ingesting from gz files? If I unzip the files before ingesting, they grow in size very big.

I did a search on the Elasticsearch forum, but could not find anything useful.

Comment: check this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-to-stream-gz-logs-to-es-ls/121081

Answer (score 3):

Filebeat doesn't support gz files right now. But there is an ongoing request for that, you can track the progress here.

https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/637

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat will not be able to properly consume contents inside GZIP files.
It will read it but the output will be unreadable *i.e. UTF-8 encoded garbage.*
The Elastic team suggest such files get excluded, see below.

`exclude_files: ['\.gz$']`

For further details please check the following link:
[discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-to-stream-gz-logs-to-es-ls/121081](http://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-to-stream-gz-logs-to-es-ls/121081)